# I just finished the typewriter set and everything works fine but the type-bar is a little higher than it should be. Is there any way of fixing it

Tags: technic, building, sets, disassembly, ideas

The typewriter works perfectly fine. The only problem is the typebar being a little higher than it should be.

Comment: Please add a photo to your question.

Comment: I've built this set and the typebar that works is more raised than the others. I believe that is intentional/unavoidable, but one thing you can do is raise the other ones to be more inline with the middle one.